# Coldfusion CFFORM scriptSrc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-7, cfform

I have a series of coldfusion forms that I would like to not have to modify if possible.  Is there a way to set the cfform scriptSrc attribute from application.cfc?

Comment: It's an [admin setting](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/774.cfm) not an Application.cfc one, though I'm not sure if it existed in CF7.

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not have access the the admin settings. Thanks Peter!

Comment: Is changing the default setting of a tag attribute possible without the admin?

Comment: In general, no. (Not in CF7 that is. Railo 4 supports doing that, but I guess switching would be a bigger issue than just adding the attribute to the cfform tags). Actually, what is the reason for not wanting to modify existing cfform tags - if it's just effort then it can be done pretty easy with a regex search replace.